# Jenkins 2.32.1 start fails due to method deleteWinstoneTempContents

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, service

I'm trying to start my Jenkins 2.32.1 instance (as a service or manually) and each of the commands fail. In jenkins.log I can see these messages:

```
Aug 14, 2017 9:15:03 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Aug 14, 2017 9:15:03 AM Main _main
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary file /tmp/dummy5617365540558096686dummy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: winstone.Launcher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at Main._main(Main.java:224)
        at Main.main(Main.java:112)
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Aug 14, 2017 9:15:29 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Aug 14, 2017 9:15:29 AM Main _main
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary file /tmp/dummy9095626099550598267dummy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: winstone.Launcher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at Main._main(Main.java:224)
        at Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

What surprises me is that there is no `/tmp/dummy9095626099550598267dummy` or `/tmp/winstone/jenkins.war` on the machine. Any idea on how I could start my Jenkins instance again?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We restarted the machine and the problem disappeared... but for how long?...

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem. It only happens when you issue a restart command
`sudo service jenkins restart`.

Though I couldn't understand reason behind the error. Instead using a restart, I   used stop and start commands which worked fine.

`sudo service jenkins stop`

`sudo service jenkins start`